# Prove that ρ is a partial order on A.

Tags: relations

Let $a_1, a_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $a_i \ne a_j$ when $i \ne j$, and let $A = \{a_1, a_2,\ldots\}$. Define a relation $\rho$ on $A$ as follows. For all $a_i, a_j\in A$, $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_j$ if and only if $i \le j$ and $a_i\le a_j$. Prove that $\rho$ is a partial order on $A$.

Comment: Is 6= supposed to be $\ne$?

Comment: Yes. That's right. Sorry

Comment: @dstar19, the two questions you posted in the last hour ([here's the other one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964740/prime-equivalence-relations)) don't have any context, thoughts, descriptions of what you have tried, or anything. It looks very much like you just want other people to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: This time you have to show that $\rho$ is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive.

**Reflexivity:** If $a_i\in A$, then it’s certainly true that $i\le i$ and $a_i\le a_i$, so $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_i$. Thus, $\mathrel{\rho}$ is reflexive.

**Antisymmetry:** You need to show that if $a_i,a_j\in A$, $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_j$, and $a_j\mathrel{\rho}a_i$, then $a_i=a_j$. Note that if $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_j$, then $i\le j$ and $a_i\le a_j$. In similar fashion translate the hypothesis that $a_j\mathrel{\rho}a_i$ into statements not involving $\rho$, and see if you can see why it must be true that $a_i=a_j$.

**Transitivity:** You need to show that if $a_i,a_j,a_k\in A$, $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_j$, and $a_j\mathrel{\rho}a_k$, then $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_k$. Here again you should translate the hypotheses that $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_j$ and $a_j\mathrel{\rho}a_k$ into statements that don’t involve $\rho$. For instance, the first one means that $i\le j$ and $a_i\le a_j$. If you put everything together, you should be able to deduce something about the relationship between $i$ and $k$ and the relationship between $a_i$ and $a_k$. Then translate the desired conclusion, $a_i\mathrel{\rho}a_k$, into statements that don’t involve $\rho$, to see just what it is that you’re really trying to deduce from the hypotheses.